# Go to implementation Intellij return .class file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I navigate to implementation of the stream() method, I get this weird look:

[image]

Why go to implementation let to compiled file. What's caused this error and how to solves it?.

Comment: Why do you think this is an error? You wanted to see the implementation of said method and after clicking it it shows you said implementation...

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS: I don't think this is an error. I wanna get into `Collection.java` file instead of the `Collection.class` file.

Comment: Intellij doesn't have sources of that class but it has compiled code. It tried to show you at least decompiled one. You have to download sources to be able to explore those.

Comment: @Amongalen: I already have JDK 18 available was configured on Intellij.

Comment: JDK 18? I assume you mean 1.8?

Comment: @MCEmperor: Yes. Exactly

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project Structure then under Platform Settings, click on SDKs, and then click on "1.8" or "11" or "13" or whatever version of the JDK you're using. Then click on "Sourcepath". Make sure the correct source directory/zip file is mentioned in there. It is possible you upgraded your JDK and didn't update the JDK source.

Comment: I'll try, but it's was happen on my machine at home. And in another case, when I add a new library to my project (.jar), I was faced the same problem. What should I do? @DodgyCodeException

Answer (score 0):

Your ide allows you to explore classes from libraries, that is what you see, an external class from a lib. there is no error with that.

Answer (score 0):

The stream() method is from the Collections class, which is from the Java Collections Framework. What you are looking at is the decompiled bytecode of the method, rather than the source code, which would be a .java file. To view the source code, download the source.

Comment: No need to download the source since the JDK distribution includes the source - in file _src.zip_.